# How to stop Visual studio/IIS express from creating new <site> every time it is restarted in applicationhost.config

Tags: visual-studio-2012, iis-express

I am developing a web application in visual studio 2012 and every time I close and open visual studio it creates a new  entry with default settings in IIS express's applicationhost.config and since I am using a browser from another machine (windows is in a vm) I have to go into applicationhost.config and fix the binding to * rather than localhost so I can browse to the website.

This is starting to get pretty annoying and I have searched online but I couldn't find any info on it. Does anybody happen to know how to stop this from happening?

Answer (score 16):

Inside the bindings section of the site section, create a new binding in addition to the localhost version like so:

```
 <bindings>
     <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:21232:localhost" />
     <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:21232:*" />
 </bindings>
```

After having both lines, VS stopped making new site sections.

Comment: With VS2015 this does not bind the site to other IP addresses for me. However, it seems that if I add other addresses in addition to `*:21232:*`, e.g. `192.168.1.1:21232:*` VS keeps the setting after restarting.

Comment: I found that the order of these lines was significant - if I place the binding with the asterisk (*) first, then VS2017 kept creating new <site> elements, but in the order shown - it works just great.

Comment: Remember to run VS as admin, or else the binding might not work

Answer (score 3):

Have you set the URL it should use in the project csproj file? You can lock it down there to localhost and a port number :)

For example:

```
<ProjectExtensions>
    <VisualStudio>
      <FlavorProperties GUID="{whatever your guid is}">
        <WebProjectProperties>
          <UseIIS>True</UseIIS>
          <AutoAssignPort>False</AutoAssignPort>
          <DevelopmentServerPort>12345</DevelopmentServerPort>
          <DevelopmentServerVPath>/</DevelopmentServerVPath>
          <IISUrl>**http://localhost:portnum**/IISUrl>
          <NTLMAuthentication>False</NTLMAuthentication>
          <UseCustomServer>False</UseCustomServer>
          <CustomServerUrl>
          </CustomServerUrl>
          <SaveServerSettingsInUserFile>False</SaveServerSettingsInUserFile>
        </WebProjectProperties>
      </FlavorProperties>
    </VisualStudio>
  </ProjectExtensions>
```

Answer (score 0):

He wasn't asking to change TO localhost, he was asking how to tell Visual Studio not to restrict to localhost.  Essentially, every time he restarts Visual Studio, he has to open up the applicationhost.config file for IIS Express and change localhost to an asterik so his host machine can connect to his VM to test the website.

I experience the same problem.  My workaround is to set the IP address in the Project properties under the URL, and connect to the IP address from the host machine instead.

Comment: Where exactly is this `URL` property? I cannot seem to find it.